# Any good threads related job-interview question?

Tags: language-agnostic, multithreading

When interviewing graduates I usually ask them questions about data structures, algorithms and complexity theory. I would really like to ask a question that will enable them to show their familiarity with multi-threaded concepts, without dwelling into language specific issues.

Any good questions? The only question I could think of is how to write a Singleton that supports multi-threaded access.

Comment: Man, I'd fail at the job interview because I don't bother with locks, etc.  Using a language designed for sane concurrency has its advantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the classic "write me a consumer-producer queue" question to be quite good.  You can talk about synchronization in a handwavy way beforehand for five minutes or so (e.g. start with "What does `Object.wait()` do?  What other methods on `Object` is it related to?  Can you give me an example of when you might use these?  What other concurrency techniques might you use in practice [because really, it's quite rare that actually using the wait/notify primitives is the best approach]?").  Make sure the candidate addresses (or at least makes clear he is aware of) both atomicity ("missed updates") and volatility (visibility of the new value on other threads)

Then after you've had a chat about the theory of these, get them to spend a few minutes actually writing the code for a primitive producer-consumer queue.  This should be straightforward to anyone who actually understands what they were talking about above, yet it will weed out those who can "talk the talk" but don't actually understand it in practice (arguably the most dangerous group).

What I like about these mini-coding exercises, is that they're often easy to extend.  For instance, if the candidate completes the task easily, you can ask how they would extend it for situation XXX - invent requirements that you know will push the limits of the noddy solution you asked for.  This not only lets you tailor the depth of questions you're asking but gives some insight into how well the candidate handles clarification of requirements, and modifications of existing design (which is pretty important in this industry).

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find some topics to discuss:

- threads implementation ( kernel vs user space)
- thread local storage
- synchronization primitives
- deadlocks, livelocks

Answer (score 1):

- Differences between mutex and
  semaphore.
- Use of condition variables.
- When not to use threads. (eg. IO multiplexing)

Answer (score 1):

Talk with them about a popular, but not well-known topic, where thread handling is essential.

I recommend you, build a **web server** with them, of course, only on paper or just in words. The result should look something like this: there is a main thread, it's listening on a socket. When something arrives, it passes the socket into the pool, then this thread returns back to socket listening. The pool has fixed number of slots. The request processing threads are dedicated to get job from the pool. Find out, what's better, if the threads are checking the pool concurrently, or the listner main thread selects a free slot/thread for the new incoming request. Try to write a small pseudocode, or a graph for both side of the pool handling.

Let's introduce a small application: **page counter**, which tells that how many page request has been made since server startup. Don't tell them that the counter must be protected against concurrent modification, let them to find it out how to do this with mutexes or synchronization or whatsoever. Maybe you could skip the web server part, the page counter app is easier to specify.

Another example is a **chat**, with 2+ clients and a server, find out, how to solve the problem, that all the messages should arrive in the same order for all clients. Or **reflex game**: the server waits for 1..5 secs random, then says "peek-a-boo", and the player wins who presses space key first. Specify it with 2 player, then try to expand it to N players.

---

Also, be aware of NPPs. NPP stands: "non-programming programmer". There are dudes, who can talk about programming issues, they know all the 3/4-letter abbrevations (there're *lot* in the Java world, EJB, JSP, XSLT, and my favourite: POJO, which means Pure Old Java Objects, lol), they understand and modify codes, or make similar programs from a base, but they fail even with small problems, it it has to do it theirselves, e.g. finding the nearest element to a base in an array. Sometimes it takes months, until it turns out. They performs well at interviews, because they prepare for it. Maybe they don't even known, that they're NPPs, this is a known effect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning-Kruger_effect

It's hard to recognize the opposite dudes, who have not heard about trendy libraries or patterns, but they can learn it even at the job interview. (Personal remark: my last interview was in 1999, and it seems that I will not do interview anymore. I have never heard of dynamic web pages before, but I've figured out the term "session" during the interview, the question was that how to build a simple hanging man web app. I was hired.)